# "What I have, I give [it to] others"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, repetition

Can I say "What I have, I give others", or do I have to say "What I have, I give it to others"? In the latter case, the object is repeated: 'it' and 'what I have'.

Answer (score 2):

English!

I feel sure almost everybody would find

> "I give others / other people what I have."

acceptable. But

> "I give what I have to other people."

needs the *to*.

And

> "What I have, I give to others."

again needs the *to* (though the *it* is better dropped).